# Completely remove Vagrant VirtualBox boxes from command line

Tags: linux, ubuntu, networking, virtualbox, vagrant

Every time a `Vagrant` box fails to install, it leaves some mess behind in `VirtualBox`. **Forwarded ports** that were set up in the `Vagrantfile` **do not get cleaned up**. `vagrant halt` does not work because the box is not up, and `vagrant destroy` sometimes work, depending on how far the installation of a box went before hanging.

So every time I test a new setup, vagrant says that the port to be forwarded is already in use. I need to change the port to forward, and then the install continues, only to hang at a later point and take the port hostage into oblivion. Now I don't have any ports that I can use (that are accessible remotely), so I just want to quit having those ports constipated.

I could probably fix this with a reboot, but the machine cannot be rebooted right now.

Issuing the *"just delete the damn thing"* command does not work:

> $ **VBoxManage list vms**
>   "<inaccessible>" {aaaa-aa-aa-aa-aaaa}
>   "<inaccessible>" {bbbb-bb-bb-bb-bbbb}
>   "vagrant_default_cccc_cc" {cccc-cc-cc-cc-cccc}
>   $ **VBoxManage unregistervm aaaa-aa-aa-aa-aaaa --delete**
>   VBoxManage: error: The object is not ready
>   VBoxManage: error: Details: code E_ACCESSDENIED (0x80070005), component Machine, interface IMachine, callee nsISupports
>   VBoxManage: error: Context: "Delete(ComSafeArrayAsInParam(aMedia), pProgress.asOutParam())" at line 165 of file VBoxManageMisc.cpp
>   $ **VBoxManage unregistervm bbbb-bb-bb-bb-bbbb --delete**
>   VBoxManage: error: The object is not ready
>   VBoxManage: error: Details: code E_ACCESSDENIED (0x80070005), component Machine, interface IMachine, callee nsISupports
>   VBoxManage: error: Context: "Delete(ComSafeArrayAsInParam(aMedia), pProgress.asOutParam())" at line 165 of file VBoxManageMisc.cpp
>   $ **VBoxManage unregistervm cccc-cc-cc-cc-cccc --delete**
>   VBoxManage: error: Cannot unregister the machine 'vagrant_default_cccc_cc' while it is locked
>   VBoxManage: error: Details: code VBOX_E_INVALID_OBJECT_STATE (0x80bb0007), component Machine, interface IMachine, callee nsISupports
>   VBoxManage: error: Context: "Unregister(fDelete ? (CleanupMode_T)CleanupMode_DetachAllReturnHardDisksOnly : (CleanupMode_T)CleanupMode_DetachAllReturnNone, ComSafeArrayAsOutParam(aMedia))" at line 160 of file VBoxManageMisc.cpp
>   $

(Nope, `sudo` doesn't do the trick either.)

How can I totally eradicate and destroy the machines as easily as possible without having to reboot? Or, at least (or better) stop `VirtualBox` from keeping port forwards to broken boxes? I probably should not remove and `-rf` just everything because there are also some boxes that run fine.

The server running Vagrant and VirtualBox runs on `Ubuntu 13.10`. The guest, although probably irrelevant, tries to run `Ubuntu 12.10`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$ ps axu|grep VBoxHeadless
jamie     4205  0.3  1.2 1592676 208592 ?      Sl   Apr10   7:08 /usr/lib/virtualbox/VBoxHeadless --comment apt-cacher_default_1396256757 --startvm a8c2157a-f86f-491d-a703-74e49b4348fb --vrde config
jamie    11390 48.7  1.4 2823080 231788 ?      Sl   Apr10 845:49 /usr/lib/virtualbox/VBoxHeadless --comment vandeliverytest_default_1397122355 --startvm a06a0a8c-a645-4270-89f4-992566e111f0 --vrde config
jamie    22226  0.0  0.0  13596   936 pts/3    S+   16:31   0:00 grep --color=auto VBoxHeadless
```

The "startvm" ones are the processes that hang around and can't be stopped with normal vagrant commands.  issue a `kill -TERM` command to the processes and they should stop
If that doesn't work escalate to a `kill -KILL`